# Remove Certain Characters in Long Chain (SMS)

Tags: notepad++

I have a long .xml file of SMS with some messages in this format:

```
<sms protocol="0" address=" (xxx) xxx-xxxx" date="1349121360000" type="2" subject="null" body="Body of the SMS is here" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="0" readable_date="Oct 1, 2012 3:56:00 PM" contact_name="(Unknown)" />
```

I want to replace **only** the address field with a standardized format of

`address=xxxxxxxxxx"` rather than `address=" (xxx) xxx-xxxx"`

Without this format, phones don't thread the messages properly. I have tried lots of combinations of regular expressions but coming up dry.

Comment: A simpler way of rephrasing - is there an easy find and replace to remove all non-numeric characters in the `address="x"` section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Find What: `\s\((\d\d\d)\)\s(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)`
- Replace With: `\1\2\3`

So the regex is looking for `space` + `(` + digit+digit+digit + `)` + `space` + digit+digit+digit + `-` + digit+digit+digit+digit.

The other (non-escaped) brackets create three capture groups around the Area Code, Prefix, and Suffix sections of the phone number.

The "Replace with" replaces what was found by the RegEx search with the stuff found in the 3 capture groups.

Before:

`address=" (123) 456-7890"`

After:

`address="1234567890"`

Comment: This also finds and changes numbers in the "body" field. Is there any way to restrict it to "address"?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Problem was I had already removed the leading spaces. address="\((\d\d\d)\)\s(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)"

Comment: NO problem.  You could always expand the Find What to something like `address="\s\((\d\d\d)\)\s(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)"` to narrow the matches to things starting with `address="`, then change the Replace With to include the `address=` and the quotes (`"`).